# How to detect the presence of form elements on a webpage

Tags: forms, url, web-scraping

I have a list of urls which points to distinct webpages . The task is to find out whether these webpages contain any form elements that expect confidential private information from users.

What will be the best way to design such a scraping tool? Any suggestion/third party service that's available which can readily give me this information?

Comment: You will have to write code by yourself or hire someone to do it. You can simply use Python BeautfulSoup to load pages, but remember they just load HTML and dont run any JS/AJAX code like a normal browser does. If you want to emulate real browser-like behavior then please use Python Selenium or PhantomJS

Comment: What exact information from users should be treated as confidential private?

Comment: @omegastripes DOB, phone number etc.